# How can I access an explicitly implemented method using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, explicit-implementation

Usually, I access a method in reflection like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public void M () {
        var m = this.GetType ().GetMethod ("M");
        m.Invoke(this, new object[] {}); // notice the pun
    }
}
```

However, this fails when M is an explicit implementation:

```
class Foo : SomeBase
{
    void SomeBase.M () {
        var m = this.GetType ().GetMethod ("M");
        m.Invoke(this, new object[] {}); // fails as m is null
    }
}
```

How do I access an explicitly implemented method using reflection?

Comment: In that case `M` is private. You should use the `BindingFlags` enum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because the name of the method is not `"M"`, it will be `"YourNamespace.SomeBase.M"`. So either you will need to specify that name (along with appropriate `BindingFlags`), or get the method from the interface type instead.

So given the following structure:

```
namespace SampleApp
{    
    interface IFoo
    {
        void M();
    }

    class Foo : IFoo
    {
        void IFoo.M()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("M");
        }
    }
}
```

...you can do either this:

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
obj.GetType()
    .GetMethod("SampleApp.IFoo.M", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Invoke(obj, null);
```

...or this:

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
typeof(IFoo)
    .GetMethod("M")
    .Invoke(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot rely on the name of the method on the implementing class at all - it can be anything. The C# compilers have so far used the convention of prefixing the method name with the fullname of the interface, but that is an internal implementation detail, and also won't be true for e.g. F#. The proper way is by using `InterfaceMapping` if you want a `MethodInfo` for the implementation.

For example if we have the following structure

```csharp
namespace LibBar
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class AnswerAttribute : Attribute { }

  public interface IFoo
  {
    void Hello();
    int GetAnswer();
    object WhoAmI();
  }
}
```

And in an F# project

```fs
namespace LibFoo
open LibBar

type Foo() = 
    interface IFoo with
        [<Answer>]
        member this.GetAnswer() = 42
        member this.Hello() = printf "Hello, World!"
        member this.WhoAmI() = this :> obj
```

If we just want to call `GetAnswer()` through reflection then it suffices to get the `MethodInfo` for the interface

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
int answer = (int)typeof(IFoo)
  .GetMethod("GetAnswer")
  .Invoke(obj, null);
```

However say that we want to see if the implementation has the AnswerAttribute. Then it won't be enough to just have the `MethodInfo` for the method on the interface. The name of the method would be `"LibBar.IFoo.GetAnswer"` if this had been C#, but we want it to work independent of implementation details in the compiler and language used.

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethodImplementation(Type implementationType, MethodInfo ifaceMethod)
{
  InterfaceMapping ifaceMap = implementationType.GetInterfaceMap(ifaceMethod.DeclaringType);
  for (int i = 0; i < ifaceMap.InterfaceMethods.Length; i++)
  {
    if (ifaceMap.InterfaceMethods[i].Equals(ifaceMethod))
      return ifaceMap.TargetMethods[i];
  }
  throw new Exception("Method missing from interface mapping??"); // We shouldn't get here
}

...

  Foo obj = new Foo();
  MethodInfo ifaceMethod = typeof(IFoo).GetMethod("GetAnswer");
  MethodInfo implementationMethod = GetMethodImplementation(typeof(Foo), ifaceMethod);
  Console.WriteLine("GetAnswer(): {0}, has AnswerAttribute: {1}",
    implementationMethod.Invoke(obj, null),
    implementationMethod.GetCustomAttribute<AnswerAttribute>() != null);
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional info!